# typing : how to get if a class attribute is of a type alias?

Tags: python, typing

For example:

```py
import typing

tuple2 = typing.Tuple[float,float]

class A:
  a: tuple2 = (1.,1.)

print(typing.get_type_hints(A)['a'])
```

This prints, as expected: `typing.Tuple[float, float]`

Does something simular to this exists?

```py
print(some_other_function(A)['a'])
# prints: "tuple2"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tuple2` is just a variable that refers to `typing.Tuple[float,float]`.  In general, you can't get the name of a variable based on its value, unless you do weird stuff with inspecting the variable namespace.

What you might want to do is use `typing.NewType` to define an actual new type:

```
>>> Tuple2 = typing.NewType("Tuple2", typing.Tuple[float, float])
>>> class A:
...     a: Tuple2 = Tuple2((1, 1))
...
>>> typing.get_type_hints(A)['a'].__name__
'Tuple2'
```

Note that a `NewType` is not the same as an alias; type checkers will consider it to be a subtype of the type that you derive it from, so if you declare something as a `Tuple2` you need to define it as `Tuple2((1, 1))` rather than a regular `1, 1` tuple.  In practice, the newtype always behaves exactly the same as the parent type, so if you aren't using a type checker the difference is unimportant.

If you *really* want to get the name of an alias, you could look at `globals()`, e.g.:

```
>>> tuple2 = typing.Tuple[float,float]
>>> [k for k, v in globals().items() if v == typing.Tuple[float, float]]
['tuple2']
```

but this is not great because there might well be multiple names for the same value, and if there are, there's no way at runtime to figure out *which* alias was used for a particular type.